# SVN: compare unversioned directory to version in repository

Tags: svn

A directory created by means of an export is not a working copy but I would like to know if there is any difference with the original revision.

Two simple ways that come to my mind:

- Do a checkout in the same folder, then simply `svn diff` (but: then I need to clean it up from the svn folders);
- Do a checkout into another folder, overwrite it with the files I want to check, issue `svn diff`, then remove the duplicate (but: it won't detect removed files, unless I copy with rsync).

Is there a more elegant way (e.g with `svn diff` parameters) to compare and diff an arbitrary local folder against a folder on a repository without making a checkout?

Comment: I've done your second option multiple times and that has usually done the trick for me. Another simple way to do an svn diff with a folder in a repository is to do a `diff with URL` from your local checkout to any URL. Unfortunately, it would require you to have an svn checkout.